# Leftjoin with groupby skips groupby

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have Users that I want to count by left joining table for workouts and getting one row for each user. So users that has been only once in workout table or more but I need just one row per user_id.

This works by using in within raw sql query but trying to format it within laravel it does not:

```
$users->leftJoin('workout', function($join){
  $join->on('user.id', '=', 'workout.user_id')
  ->where('workout.user_id', '>', 1)
  ->groupBy('workout.user_id');
})
```

This is a query that works as raw query:

```
select * from `users` 
left join (select workout.user_id, workout.id_holofit from workout where workout.user_id > 1  group by workout.user_id) workout ON workout.user_id = users.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the groupby outside your join closure.

```
$users->leftJoin('workout', function ($join) {
    $join->on('user.id', '=', 'workout.user_id')
    ->where('workout.user_id', '>', 1);
})
->groupBy('workout.user_id')
```

Comment: Doesnt work, returns the same amount. I will add raw query, maybe my formation is mission something.